# Getting error while making charges on connected Standalone Acount(Stripe)

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm trying to make charges on connected standalone acount. I'm using parse cloud code for that...it gives me following error:

Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "ReferenceError: stripe is not defined

Below is my code..

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('**************************');

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {

               var token = request.params.stripeToken;
               var userid = request.params.userId;
               stripe.charges.create(
                                     {
                                     amount: 1000,
                                     currency: "usd",
                                     source: token,
                                     description: "Example charge",
                                     application_fee: 123
                                     },
                                     {stripe_account: userid},{
                                     success: function(httpResponse) {
                                     response.success("Purchase made!");
                                     },
                                     error: function(httpResponse) {
                                     response.error(error);
                                     }

                                     });
});
```

Comment: ohhh...thats my mistake! It happens because i have initialized 'Stripe' and trying to call method on 'stripe'.

Comment: Now it gives me another error:  Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "success/error was not called" UserInfo={code=141, temporary=0, error=success/error was not called, NSLocalizedDescription=success/error was not called}

Comment: Parse does not support Stripe Connect

Comment: Also you should never share your API key, you should roll it immediately

Comment: not support means????exact what?

Comment: No support means that Parse uses their own version of the Stripe Library. They do not use one that Stripe created. The one they use is from 2011 before Stripe Connect existed. Thus it is impossible to use Stripe Connect with Parse's Stripe library

Comment: Is there any alternative for this solution?

Comment: Use a different host like Heroku where you write your own integration with the latest node bindings.

Comment: Thankx koopajah . but now i'm going to setup my own server..